# Javascript cannot push to global array inside function

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I have a folder filled with json files and I am trying to push them all into an array.  However, the outer array is blank.  Any help on why this is happening or explaining a better approach would be appreciated.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dataFolder = './jsonData/';

var arr = [];
fs.readdir(dataFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        fs.readFile(dataFolder + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            arr.push(data);
            console.log (arr); // correct output
        })
    })
})
console.log (arr);  //output is []
```

Sorry for how ugly it looks, but here's some of the output from the inner array:

[ '{\n    "title": "A New Kind of Science [Hardcover]",\n    "author": "Stephen Wolfram",\n    "price": "$20.73",\n    "shippingWeight": "5.6 pounds",\n    "isbn10": "1579550088"\n}' ]

[ '{\n    "title": "A New Kind of Science [Hardcover]",\n    "author": "Stephen Wolfram",\n    "price": "$20.73",\n    "shippingWeight": "5.6 pounds",\n    "isbn10": "1579550088"\n}',
  '{\n    "title": "I Wear the Black Hat: Grappling with Villains (Real and Imagined) [Hardcover]",\n    "author": "Chuck Klosterman",\n    "price": "$15.49",\n    "shippingWeight": "2.2 pounds",\n    "isbn10": "1439184496"\n}' ]

Comment: does ur foreach gets called?

Comment: can u paste what u see in the dev console in the question too?

Comment: thats exactly my thought ... its possible that its aync lol.. since that anonymous function is a callback.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @max Yeah the forEach is getting called. I updated the with the output.  Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: I think you wanted to notify @Mox .

Comment: @mox Yeah the forEach is getting called. I updated the with the output. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readdir` is asynchronous it has not executed by the time you get to your `console.log`.

1. `var arr = [];` - set the `arr` to an empty array.
2. `fs.readdir(....)` go read the directory in the back ground and schedule the callback to execute after readdir background job is done **and** this file has finished excuting.
3. `console.log(arr);` print arr as it is now (empty).
4. readdir is done **and** there is nothing else left on the call stack so *now* we can finally execute the callback.
5. start pushing to `arr`.
6. `console.log(arr);` print arr as it is now (finally populated).

Also global state is a source of much confusion and bugs. Try to design your code so it does not rely on global state. (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/16887)